# Sparse Git checkout of files into parent directory

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

Borrowing from a few tutorials, I am able to do a sparse checkout of a particular folder in a git repo.

```
mkdir git-completion && cd git-completion
git init
git remote add –f origin https://github.com/git/git.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo contrib/completion/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

For example, let's say that I am after the `git-completion.bash`, `git-completion.tcsh`, etc scripts that are in the `contrib/completion` folder of this repo.

The above sparse-checkout does return me the desired folder, but it seems to have a nested file strucure:

```
git-completion/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
```

Is it possible to pull the files instead into the parent directory like so?

```
git-completion/git-completion.bash
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to extract the files from the git repository? Do you want to still be able to track changes and commit them?

Comment: If I recall, I wanted to still track and commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `git show`:

```
git show <revision>:path/to/file.txt > different/path/to/otherfile.txt
```

In your specific case:

```
git show HEAD:git-completion/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash > git-completion/git-completion.bash
```

Repeat for each file you want to checkout. Although, really, the reason for the subdirectories, I think, is that when these get bundled into a `git` release, they're put in the `contrib/completion` subdirectory, so it might just be better to get used to the repository layout...

Comment: Would I be right in thinking this is like a git version of a symlink? This definitely works, but repeating for each file is highly inconvenient if there are a lot of files in the sub-folder (and more directories too).

Comment: No, it's basically just retrieving the content of a file from the repository and storing it somewhere else. In fact, if you do `git status` it will show it as a new untracked file, and if you do `git add`, it will consider it a copy/rename from the original path.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you have two options.  If you want to be able to track changes to the files still, then I would commit symlinks.  If you don't care about local changes, then I would use `git archive`.

## Commit symlinks

You can commit symlinks to the files that you care about, use spare checkout to get those as well.

```
ln -s contrib/completion/git-completion.bash git-completion.bash
git add git-completion.bash
```

This will allow you to edit the files and commit changes to them still.

## Git archive

This will simply extract the content you are looking for.  Changes will not be tracked in the repository.

```
# generic
git archive <revision>:<path> | tar -xf -

#specific to your example
git clone --bare https://github.com/git/git.git ~/git-completion-bare
mkdir git-completion && cd git-completion
git archive --remote ~/git-completion-bare master:contrib/completion/ | tar -xf -
```

---

Edit: It looks like `github` does not support `git archive --remote`.  It is still included below in case someone is using a different hosting service that allows it.

## Git archive with --remote

Using git archive, you can even download the changes directly from a remote repository without cloning the repository first.  The downside is you cannot track local changes with Git.

```
# General form
git archive --remote <url> <revision>:<path> | tar -xf -
# your example 
git archive --remote https://github.com/git/git.git master:contrib/completion/ | tar -xf -
```

You will now have the files in the current directory.